# Run terminal inside VS Code for python script?

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code

I'm on Linux Mint running VSCode and I was somehow able to run a terminal not as a separate window but right below an open Python file.  Seems to be easy on Win/OSX (Ctrl/Cmd+J and select Terminal tab) but not specifically a feature that I can choose when I'm on a Linux machine.  Any special keys to bring it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, Ctrl-` opens the integrated terminal in VS Code. Otherwise look under the `View` menu for the `Integrated Terminal` option. If you're looking for Python-specific options, there are `Run Python File in Terminal` and `Run Python Selection/Line in Terminal` commands from the command palette.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't have any of that so I reinstalled and now it's working.  I seemed to have had an older version.  I have two computers and the other one had the updated version.  Cheers